# Is oblivious appropriate here?

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning, adjectives

I was distracted by his overgrown front yard lawn, while he seemed completely **oblivious** to its appearance.

The intention is that he's so unconcerned about how his front yard looks that it seems like he's unaware of it. Is *oblivious* fitting to that context? Would another word be better?

Comment: Of course, there are synonyms, but *oblvious* seems to be a good choice.

Comment: I'm good with oblivious here. It strikes the right sense, based on what you've written. Oblivious totally fits with unaware and, more to the point, unaware of something that should be quite obvious.